# Running GUI apps on docker container with a MacBookPro host

Tags: macos, docker, socat, xquartz

I have been trying to follow the instructions on https://learning-continuous-deployment.github.io/docker/images/dockerfile/2015/04/22/docker-gui-osx/ about running GUI apps in a docker container inside a MacBookPro host (using Docker tools).

I created a simple docker container using Fedora 23 and with firefox installed.

I try to run firefox and after about a minute I get the following error:

```
Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported: 192.168.57.3:0
Error: cannot open display: 192.168.57.3:0
```

Does anyone have a clue what the error means and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On a Mac you may find the following steps useful:

1. Install XQuartz
2. Open it, goto preferences > Security and check the option to allow connections from network clients
3. Reboot
4. Start XQuartz (from the applications folder or with `open -a XQuartz`)
5. Allow incoming connections from your ip with `xhost + $IP` (see note 1)
6. Run firefox in your docker container (see note 2)

**Note 1**: Here's a neat trick toget your ip address:

```
export IP=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}')
```

**Note 2**: And an example docker run command to start firefox

```
docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$IP:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix <image> firefox
```

Comment: Thanks.  As far as I can remember this is the procedure I followed.  I no longer have a macbookpro and can not verify.

Comment: Step 3 is important! Logging out and back in is not enough!

Comment: This worked brilliantly. Should be the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. Question: why do we have to get the actual address of the net adapter? Why can't we use 127.0.0.1 if all this is happening on a single host? Unrelated: `grep ... | awk ...` is always redundant. You can always add a match clause to awk: `grep abc | awk '$1=="xyz"'` becomes `awk '$0~/abc/ && $1=="xyz"'`. Here though, event that's redundant, since `grep inet` is always true for rows whose first column equals `"inet"`; you can just drop the grep command.

Comment: I now am back to using a MacBookPro.  I do not know why this solution did not previously work for me, but it does now.  So I can personally verify it works.  Maybe it works on modern MacBookPros and not on older models.  Don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Rebooting my laptop fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Something to do with XQuartz or xhost right after setting everything up.

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing the same error and unfortunately rebooting did not solve the problem for me. However, I was able to get it working by mounting and pointing to my local .Xauthority file:

```
IP=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}')
docker run --rm  --name firefox -e DISPLAY=$IP:0 -e XAUTHORITY=/.Xauthority --net host -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v ~/.Xauthority:/.Xauthority  jess/firefox
```

Of course, this assumes your XQuarts/xhost stuff is properly configured according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47309184/4123514)